# DJI SDK Can't start coordinated Waypoint mission

Tags: c++, ros, dji-sdk

I am creating WaypointMission using DJI ROS SDK.
I want my vehicle to pass smoothly through provided waypoints, so I set enable coordinated mode like so:

```
waypoint_task.trace_mode = dji_sdk::MissionWaypointTask::TRACE_COORDINATED;
```

The problem is, no matter how many or how dense control points are, SDK always responds with error message `WAYPOINT_MISSION_POINTS_NOT_ENOUGH`:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzQCd.png)

With `TRACE_POINT` mission uploads successfully, but those stops at waypoints are no good for filmmaking.

Also, where I can find information about actions I can execute on waypoints using `dji_sdk/MissionWaypointAction.msg`?

Answer (score 0):

I've It's been about 6 months since I used the onboard SDK, so it may have been fixed by now, but when I was using the ROS version, one of the bugs I found was that after you upload "two many" waypoints, the waypoint mission won't work. If I recall correctly, that number was around 28. So, if you have a waypoint mission with 27 waypoints, it would work, but 28 wouldn't. Also, it was cumulative, so if you did a waypoint mission with 10 waypoints, and later did one with 18, the second would fail, and you wouldn't be able to do a waypoint mission again until you restarted.

I also tried the non-ros version of the SDK. It worked better, but was also buggy and hard to use, and wouldn't allow more than 99 waypoints in a mission.